# Properties of Orlicz spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, orlicz-spaces

suppose we have an Orlicz function $\Phi$ which is an N function and $\Psi$ be its complementary function.

1. It is given that the following are equivalent
   (a) $\Phi \in \Delta_2$ [Which says that $\Phi(2x)\leq K\Phi(x)$ for some $K>0$.]
   (b) $\Psi \in \nabla_2$ [Which says that $\Psi(y)\leq \frac{1}{2q} \psi(qx)$ for $q>1.$]
2. If $\Phi \in \Delta_2$ is an N-function then $\Phi(x) \leq C|x|^{\alpha}$ for some $C>0$) and $\alpha>1$ and its complementary function $\Psi \in \nabla_2$ satisfy $\psi(y) \geq D|y|^{\beta}$ for some $D>0$ and $\beta >1$.

Now suppose I assume both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are in the intersection of $\Delta_2$ and $\nabla_2$ will the above two properties still hold?

similarly, if suppose there is some property related to the Orlicz space which says that something is true if $\Phi \in \Delta_2$ and suppose I took $\Phi\in \Delta_2 \cap \nabla_2$ will the property still hold?